# In C#, How to create a define and use a class hierarchy derived from an enum value?

Tags: c#

Given an enum type:

```
public enum Work
{
    Normal,
    Extended
}
```

What I would like to do is the following.

```
public abstract class Builder<T>
{
    public static Builder<T> GetBuilder<T> (T work)
    {
        return new Builder<T> ();
    }
}

public class BuilderNormal : Builder<Work.Normal>
{
}

public class BuilderExtended : Builder<Work.Extended>
{
}
```

I specifically want to avoid using a switch/case in Builder or using a mapping that I would need to maintain when I would add a new enum value to Work, i.e. I could do this

```
public abstract class Builder
{
    public static Builder GetBuilder (Work work)
    {
        switch (work)
        {
            case Work.Normal:
                return new BuilderNormal ();

            case Work.Extended:
                return new BuilderExtended ();

            default:
                throw new ...
        }
    }
}
```

So, basically, I want to create an instance of a class depending on an enum value and the class must be a child class of an abstract class.

Comment: Why do you think this is generic?

Comment: You're right, not totally generic. I'm trying to get "genericity" on the value of the enum to get the proper derived class instance.

Comment: Why have a enum? See my answer, its not somthing I actually suggest you do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't in the way you've designed, basically. Generic type parameters are always for *types*, not *values*.

What you *can* certainly do is maintain a single `Dictionary<Work, Func<Builder>>` to allow you to basically register factories. That will avoid the switch statement, but it's still somewhere that you could forget to add values.

I'd rely on unit tests to avoid the problem though - write a test which checks that you can create a `Builder` for every value within the enum; then if you ever add a value to the enum without adding a mapping, your test will fail.

EDIT: Another option would be to add an attribute to the enum values to say which builder type corresponds to that value. You'd then need to extract that type with reflection and instantiate it that way.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So is there a pattern or technique I can use?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid, maintaining BOTH the enum and the dictionary. However, since I use unit tests already for the project, I will use your advice and add a test for checking that all the enum values have a corresponding class.

Comment: @Stécy: See my next edit for an *option* for maintaining it in one place, but it wouldn't be as clean IMO.

Comment: Well, that option as the merit of simplifying the maintenance. I was thinking of something in the same vain by using type discovery kinda like IOC container do. How about that?

Comment: @Stécy: Well you could use a convention for the enum value name to builder name, but personally I'd just go for switch or dictionary + unit tests. It's *really* not much in terms of maintenance.

Comment: Yes, I concur. That would be the solution I would use (dictionary + unit tests) and that's the solution I used for the past years. I was challenging the idea that there got to be a better way and it would seem that simplicity is the winner as always. Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: @Stécy is some sort of dirty search of constructors what you are looking for? I don't think I fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something pointless, crazy and slow like

```
public abstract class Builder
{
    public static TBuilder GetBuilder<TBuilder>() where TBuilder : Builder
    {
        var ctors = typeof(TBuilder).GetConstructors(
            BindingFlags.Instance | 
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
            BindingFlags.Public);

        var matchingCtor = ctors.Single(
            ci =>
                {
                    var paramInfo = ci.GetParameters();

                    if (paramInfo.Length != parameters.Length)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return !paramInfo.Where((t, i) =>
                        t.ParameterType != parameters[i].GetType()).Any();
                });

        return (TBuilder)matchingCtor.Invoke(parameters);
    }
}
```

which would give you a kind of static generic instance constructor, so you could do,

```
var builderNormal = Builder.GetBuilder<BuilderNormal>();
```

but, why not just call the instance constructor directly?